# Passing class object as argument in Windows 8 C++ App

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, parameter-passing, windows-store-apps, c++-cx

I want to pass a simple class object from one XAML page to another in a C++ Windows 8 application. I have created a class in App.xaml.h:

```
ref class StaticInfo sealed {
    public:
        property Platform::String^ sName;
    };
```

I haved added this to MainPage.xaml to navigate to Page2.xaml:

```
    void StaticApp::MainPage::Button_Click_1(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    StaticInfo^ StaticData;
    StaticData->sName=ClickText->Text;
    Frame->Navigate(Page2::typeid,StaticData);
}
```

And then received the smart pointer in Page2:

```
void Page2::OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs^ e)
{
    (void) e;   // Unused parameter
    StaticInfo^ data = (StaticInfo^)e->Parameter;
}
```

I get this error when I navigate to Page2:

Unhandled exception at 0x003A5EE1 in StaticApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000010.

Can anyone tell me the exact way to do it. If possible please provide a link that teaches passing data between pages. What if I want to pass multiple objects of different classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually create the StaticInfo object before you start using it:

```
 StaticInfo^ StaticData = ref new StaticInfo();
 StaticData->sName=ClickText->Text;
```

Comment: A thousand thanks for solving what I've been trying for days! Can you please tell me the way to pass more than one objects of different classes? I'll be really grateful :)

Comment: Why don't you pass a container (i.e. a single object) to all the data you need?

Comment: Okay! I'll search on containers. Haven't used them before. Anyways thanks for the help :)